# How do I get JS to recognise an array insted of characters?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am posting back a string from c# to JavaScript;

The string received looks like this:

```
arr = "[["A","B","C"],["D","E","F"]]";
```

I want to pass this to a function to create a table body in HTML but JavaScript always reads this as a string of chars NOT as an array - even when I use Array.from in example below:

```
CreatePositionsBodt(arr);

function CreatePositionsBodt(arr) {
     alert(arr);
     var asArr = Array.from(arr);    function 
}
```

Comment: You can use `JSON.parse(arr)` in your CreatePositionsBodt function.

Comment: change the surrounding quotes to apostrophe `arr = '[["A","B","C"],["D","E","F"]]';`

Comment: the thing is... the string he built in c# is not converted to an array containing strings of array, i am not familiar with ASP but i believe what you want to achieve OP is to send array from your controller to HTML and process it, is that what your post is about?
https://www.google.com.ph/#q=asp+pass+array+to+javascript

Comment: from the question it is not clear how it should be understood. I presume it should be an array of arrays o strings. OP, could you clarify pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the surrounding quotes to apostrophe `var arr = '[["A","B","C"],["D","E","F"]]';`

and use `eval()` or `JSON.parse()`

`var arr = '[["A","B","C"],["D","E","F"]]';
var myArray = eval(arr);`

or

`var arr = '[["A","B","C"],["D","E","F"]]';
var myArray = JSON.parse(arr);`

note: if you have not done so in previous invisible lines of code, use `var`